# django render html tags passed from views.py

Tags: python, django

I want my user to be able to write, for example *image1* and use a regex to recognize and replace that with an  tag.  I have it all working -- but when I pass the data to template for display I do so like this:

```
    <div class="container">
        <p>
            {% articleTxt %}
        </p>
    </div>
```

ArticleTxt contains:

```
This is a test Article <img src="/media/articleImages/django-allauth.png"> 
and that was a picture and this is another one then some more text ---- 
original: This is a test Article *image1* and that was a picture and this is 
another one *image2* then some more text
```

Thats my frustration. I've tried changing the template  to:

```
{% autoescape off %} {{articleTXT}} {{% autoescape %}}
```

I also tried

```
{{% articleTXT|safe %}}
```

It always prints the tags instead of rendering them.   Is there anyway to render tags embedded in text passed from views.py to my template!!

Comment: I am not understanding whats in `articleTXT` ? its `img` or `text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{ articleTXT |safe }}
```

or

```
{% autoescape off %} {{ articleTXT }} {% endautoescape %}
```

should do the trick

***Note: its {% endautoescape %}**

if that isnt working try,

```
format_html(articleTXT)
```

in your views.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: format_html worked for me!! The rest did not! so the solution was to add from django.utils.html import format_html and then to use processedText = format_html(processed_Text)   Thank you THANKYOU THANKYOU

Comment: awesome :D Glad that it helped.